# CloudWatch event has been triggered but my ECS task didn't run. why?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have an ECS task that's being invoked everyday by a cron schedule form a CloudWatch event. I noticed that my ECS task hasn't run today (never happened in the past) so I looked at the CloudWatch metrics (TriggeredRules & Invocations) and both shows that the corresponding event been triggered and the target been invoked successfully (also FailedInvocations metric shows zero failures). But yet again the ECS task hasn't run (no CloudWatch logs for the task today). What can be the explanation for this issue?

Comment: you should open a support case with AWS for this.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means CloudWatch successfully delivered to ECS but something went wrong in ECS. You should reach out to AWS support to check why ECS was unable to start the task. In parallel, you should check if your ECS configuration / setup was recently changed.